# Vista scheduled tasks starting late

Tags: windows-vista, scheduled-tasks

I've noticed over the past few days that my scheduled tasks in Vista are not running on time.  For example, a task set to run at 8pm runs about 45 minutes later - in fact 44-45 minutes late seems to be the norm, though one even ran 4 hours later a few days ago.

The computer clock is alright, the task settings - as far as I can tell - are fine (most of these tasks were create a couple of years ago.)

Come to think of it... This MAY have started after the time was set back one hour (I didn't change that manually - Windows took care of it and the time zone settings are fine, plus it's never been a problem before.)

Any ideas?

Comment: check you computer clock whether it affects with Day light Savings ?

Comment: The PC is 2.5 years old and it's never been an issue.  Still checked the various time settings and can't find anything that looks fishy.  This is really weird.

Comment: Ended up using Z-Cron as an alternative.  The task scheduler was just not reliable anymore.

Now upgraded to Windows 7 64-bit, though I've kept Z-Cron since I had all my stuff scheduled in there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Z-Cron as an alternative (very cool app, though the interface can be a little whiny.) The built-in task scheduler was just not reliable anymore.

I've now upgraded to Windows 7 64-bit, though I've kept Z-Cron since I had all my stuff scheduled in there already.

Answer (score 0):

Under advanced is delay task for up to x minutes set to anything?  This will add a random delay onto the scheduled start time.

Comment: Nope - that option is not checked.